# Large and complex SQL Queries with Entity Framework

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Talking about ASP.NET MVC.

How will you execute/incorporate a large SQL query with Entity Framework? Especially code-first?

I have tried with LINQ but I am finding very hard to convert large complex queries that runs fine in plain SQL to LINQ. Some queries can not be converted to LINQ at all.

What is the solution to this?

Comment: if you can't convert your queries to linq, you can send plain SQL queries (and even still map the results to your BO objects). Note however, that most complex queries can be quite simple written in linq (at least if your schema is suitable and you use the appropriate navigation properties). If that's not possible for you, the only other way I can think of is by using UDF's / stored procedures.

Comment: It's not even recommended to _convert_ complex SQL queries to LINQ.  Use LINQ when it makes your life easier, ie for new, simple queries written in C#.  If you have an existing, complex working SQL query, just continue to use that.

Comment: You can use `context.Database.SqlQuery`.